# How can I do this in less than 10 bytes of space?

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, ollydbg, patch-reversing

I have some value stored at a memory location.
I have 10 bytes of space and have following to do:

1. push registers
2. copy a string constant "abcedfghijkl" to that memory location
3. restore registers

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

YES! so possible... why wouldn't it?

I don't have resources to make sure this is 10 or less bytes, but this SHOULD be about 10 give or take 2 or 3 bytes...

use16

```
org 0x100
start:
    pusha
    mov di, memory_location
    mov al, 'a'
    mov cl, 11
    stosb
    inc al
    loop $-2
    popa
    ret

memory_location EQU 0x0100
```

If you want to COPY a string then defenently less than 10 bytes

```
    use16
org 0x100
start:
    pusha
    mov di, memory_location
    mov si, string2copy
    mov cl, 12   ; byte count to copy
    rep movsb    ; move data byte by byte from SI location to DI location
    popa
    ret

memory_location = 0x0200

;
; STRING CANT COUNT AS DATA SINCE  "abcedfghijkl" IS 12 BYTES ON IT'S OWN!
;
string2copy: 
    db "abcedfghijkl"
```

You defined nothing else, however, I don't know how this equates to reverse engineering at all though...

Comment: right idea but the code is wrong.  mov cl -> mov cx (don't know what's in ch); inc al -> inc ax (otherwise the loop stores only one character, because inc al is two bytes by itself).